# Handling button click inside bootstrap popover html content

Tags: html, jquery, bootstrap-4

I am trying to render html button inside popover and on that button's click I want to call a javascript function but through **LAPTOP'S TRACKPAD** that button onclick function is not firing.

```
<button class="seat seat-available" id="GEOJFK_32B" type="button">&nbsp;</button>

<script type="text/javascript">
$('button.seat-available').click(seat_avail_click_jquery);
var lastObjPop;

function seat_avail_click_jquery() {
    var obj = $(this);
    if (lastObjPop != null)
        lastObjPop.popover('dispose');
    lastObjPop = obj;
    var popupHtml = '<div class="seat-characteristics-popup ' + Math.random() + '"><div class="row"><div class="col-md-12"><h3 class="pax-name">Test User</h3></div></div>\
    <div class="row"><div class="col-md-6"><h3>20044<span class="seat-type">Free</span></h3></div><div class="col-md-6 text-right"><h3>$ 0</h3></div></div>\
    <div class="row"><div class="col-md-12"><button onclick="select_seat(\'DXBLHR\',\'1\',\'123\')" class="btn primary-btn select-seat">Choose</button></div></div></div>';
    obj.popover({ 'html': true, content: popupHtml, animation: true, 'trigger': 'popover' });
    obj.popover('show');
}


function select_seat(seg, paxid, id) {
console.log('here it is not coming.');
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After digging and researching a lot, I realized that adding "sanitize" will do the job.

```
obj.popover({ 'html': true, content: popupHtml, animation: true, 'trigger': 'popover',
sanitize: false //here is the magic.
});
```